# Timer freezes my WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I have read some topics about Timer, and found out that System.Timers.Timer already has threading implemented. So I used Dispatcher.Invoke, but my Timer is still freezing my window.

My code:
System.Timers.Timer

```
        int seconds = 5;
        Timer timerGetSong = new Timer();
        timerGetSong.Elapsed += (o, args) => GetSongTimer();
        timerGetSong.Interval = 1000*seconds;
```

Next method that timer triggers:

```
        private void GetSongTimer()
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(GetLastFmCurrentSong);
        }
```

And final method that is parsing from the web and assigns value to my TextBlock... Which means it takes 1-2-3 seconds to parse before it assigns value:

```
private void GetLastFmCurrentSong()
{
    CQ dom = CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://www.last.fm/user/nukec");

    string listeningNow = dom["#recentTracks:first .dateCell:first"].Text();

    string track;
    if (listeningNow.Contains("Listening now"))
    {
    track = dom["#recentTracks:first .subjectCell:first"].Text();
    track = track.Replace('\n', ' ');
    }
    else
    {
    track = "Not listening anything";
    }
    TextBlockNameSong.Text = track;
}
```

So window freezes in that time. How to properly implement this? Thank you

Comment: From what I have read, Dispatcher.Invoke is not really meant to be used for long running processes. Ideally, you should be using a background worker and use the ReportProgress method to update the ui.

Comment: Your whole `GetLastFmCurrentSong` is being dispatched to the UI thread, that's why it's being blocked. You need to only dispatch part of the code that is accessing the UI, that is, `TextBlockNameSong.Text = track;` in your `GetLastFmCurrentSong` method.

Comment: PoweredByOrange how can I do that? First time doing this, so don't know usage.

Comment: Used like this: http://pastebin.com/NMD6sbeP Can you please write this as an answer so I can mark it. THank you

Comment: @JohnMathilda Just did. You don't need to create a local dispatcher, though it's generally a good idea especially if it's necessary to distinguish different dispatchers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the whole `GetLastFmCurrentSong()` method is being dispatched to the UI thread, that is why it's blocking. You only need to dispatch part of the code that is trying to access the UI. To do this, first create a global `Dispatcher` variable for the UI thread like this:

```
private Dispatcher currentDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
```

Change your `GetSongTimer` to call the `GetLastFmCurrentSong()` method directly (or eventually have the timer's `Elapsed` event call it):

```
private void GetSongTimer()
{
    GetLastFmCurrentSong();
}
```

Finally, change your `GetLastFmCurrentSong()` to only use the dispatcher on `TextBlockNameSong.Text = track;`:

```
private void GetLastFmCurrentSong()
{
   CQ dom = CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://www.last.fm/user/nukec");

   string listeningNow = dom["#recentTracks:first .dateCell:first"].Text();

   string track;
   if (listeningNow.Contains("Listening now"))
   {
     track = dom["#recentTracks:first .subjectCell:first"].Text();
     track = track.Replace('\n', ' ');
   }
   else
   {
     track = "Not listening anything";
   }

   currentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
   {
      TextBlockNameSong.Text = track;
   }));
}
```